# Shortcut to "go to file" and "go to method" in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, keyboard-shortcuts, qt-creator

In Sublime Text I can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, then type a filename to go directly to this file. I can also type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type a method name and go to that method in the current file.

Are there equivalent shortcuts in Qt Creator?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Qt has many [shortcuts available](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-keyboard-shortcuts.html).

In particular, you can **Activate Locator** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, type your desired file name, and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

If you want to go to a specific method, activate locator and type <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> and then the name of the method. Same works for classes and <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>, and [various other things](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-locator.html#using-locator-filters). (Thanks E4z9)

If you are able to see this method in your file, clicking on it and pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> will go to its declaration or definition, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click would go to its definition.

Comment: `o` then space for opening file.